# A problem in the display of models c# opentk

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, 3d, opentk

Problem with the display of models in opentk c # I do not know where exactly the problem or where I am wrong.
I really needed help here because I could not determine the cause or the solution for this.

tip: iam edite the post

Objects must be one after another but this is the result:

[image: []

shader.fs:

```
#version 330

in vec2 texCoord0;

uniform sampler2D diffuse;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() 
{
fragColor = texture2D(diffuse, texCoord0.xy);
}
```

shader.vs:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 texCoord0;

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1.0);
texCoord0 = texCoord;
}
```

here is some codes:

```
    public static void InitGL() {


    GL.ClearColor(Color4.MidnightBlue);

        GL.FrontFace(FrontFaceDirection.Ccw);
        GL.CullFace(CullFaceMode.Back);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.CullFace);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.FramebufferSrgb);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
    }
class Mesh {
    private int vao;

    private int vbo;
    private int tcbo;
    private int nbo;
    private int ibo;
    private int size = 0;

    private Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[0];
    private Vector2[] texCoords = new Vector2[0];
    private Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[0];
    private int[] indices = new int[0];

public Mesh() {
        vbo = GL.GenBuffer();
        tcbo = GL.GenBuffer();
        nbo = GL.GenBuffer();
        ibo = GL.GenBuffer();
       vao = GL.GenVertexArray();
 }

public void AddVertices(Vector3[] positions, Vector2[] texCoords, Vector3[] normals, int[] indices) {
        size = +indices.Length;

        Vector3[] newArray = new Vector3[this.positions.Length + positions.Length];
        Array.Copy(this.positions, newArray, 0);
        Array.Copy(positions, 0, newArray, this.positions.Length, positions.Length);
        this.positions = newArray;


        Vector2[] newArray0 = new Vector2[this.texCoords.Length + texCoords.Length];
        Array.Copy(this.texCoords, newArray0, 0);
        Array.Copy(texCoords, 0, newArray0, this.texCoords.Length, texCoords.Length);
        this.texCoords = newArray0;

        Vector3[] newArray1 = new Vector3[this.normals.Length + normals.Length];
        Array.Copy(this.normals, newArray1, 0);
        Array.Copy(normals, 0, newArray1, this.normals.Length, normals.Length);
        this.normals = newArray1;

        int[] newArray2 = new int[this.indices.Length + indices.Length];
        Array.Copy(this.indices, newArray2, 0);
        Array.Copy(indices, 0, newArray2, this.indices.Length, indices.Length);
        this.indices = newArray2;

    }

    public void Complete() {
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
        GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(positions.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes), positions, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, tcbo);
        GL.BufferData<Vector2>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(texCoords.Length * Vector2.SizeInBytes), texCoords, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, nbo);
        GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(normals.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes), normals, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, ibo);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(sizeof(uint) * indices.Length), indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);

        GL.BindVertexArray(vao);

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, true, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, tcbo);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, true, Vector2.SizeInBytes, 0);

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, nbo);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(2, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, true, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, ibo);

        GL.BindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void Draw() {
        GL.BindVertexArray(vao);
        GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, size, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 ..Im Sorry sir. I posted the wrong shader and i did not notice it. i am updated the post

Comment: I can see that you have enabled the [depth test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) (`GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest)`). But anyway, the image looks like as the depth test doesn't work, because the cube in the middle, is drawn on top of the cube in front. Are you sure that you even have a depth buffer?

Comment: The third object works the depth with it, but if you look from the other side, the result will be that you can see all the object behind

Comment: I can see this and I mention that in my comment above. This behaviour can only be caused, when the depth test doesn't work and the order of the objects depends on the order of drawing.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Well, why doesn't the depth work, knowing that I am enable it?

Comment: How do you create the OpenGL window and the context? Do you set the number of depth bits explicitly?

Comment: you are solved my problem thank you. But how much number can I put? What is the difference between 1 and 2?

Comment: Its the number of bits per fragment for the depth buffer. Try 24 or 32, which is very common.

Comment: Well thank you again

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, it seems that the original user has solved the problem. Nonetheless, this is clearly a problem with the depth test. Be sure that you're clearing the depth buffer as well as the color buffer *before* drawing anything.